# Сервис не стартует, выдавая ошибку 1053

Tags: c++, visual-studio, service, visual-studio-2013, windows-service

Собираю сервис с использованием с++. За основу брал условно-рабочий [***example***](http://rsdn.ru/forum/info/FAQ.winapi.atlservice), попытки запустить сервис проводил на нем.
Запускаю код на своей машинее в дебаге/релизе/как обычное приложение/как сервис - все работает. При попытке запустить данное творение на другой машине как обычное приложение комп просто не выдает никакого окна.

В принципе, как понимаю, сервисы и не обязаны отрабатывать как обычные приложения, поэтому пытаюсь его установить как сервис.(в ком строке от имени админа `sc create SERVICENAME binpath= C:/[---].exe`) Устанавливается. Новый процесс появляется в списке сервисов, при попытке его стартануть (`sc start SERVICENAME`) комп вежливо отвечает, что

> the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

т е запуск сервиса не модет быть произведен т к сервис не отвечает. 
Как можно с этим справиться?

P.S. [вот здесь](http://rsdn.ru/File/4511/SimpleService.zip) сырцы полностью.
далее - исходный код самого сервиса

```
// SimpleService.cpp : Implementation of WinMain

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "SimpleService.h"

class CSimpleServiceModule : public CAtlServiceModuleT< CSimpleServiceModule, IDS_SERVICENAME >
{
public :
    DECLARE_REGISTRY_APPID_RESOURCEID(IDR_SIMPLESERVICE, "{01D73C58-D8F4-4A85-B27D-424443739977}")
    HRESULT InitializeSecurity() throw()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT PreMessageLoop (int nShowCmd);
    void RunMessageLoop (void) throw();
    void OnContinue (void) throw();
    void OnPause (void) throw();
    void OnShutdown (void) throw();
    void OnStop (void) throw();
};

HRESULT CSimpleServiceModule::PreMessageLoop (int nShowCmd) throw()
{
    return CAtlServiceModuleT< CSimpleServiceModule, IDS_SERVICENAME >::PreMessageLoop (nShowCmd);
}

void CSimpleServiceModule::RunMessageLoop () throw()
{
    CAtlServiceModuleT< CSimpleServiceModule, IDS_SERVICENAME >::RunMessageLoop ();
}

void CSimpleServiceModule::OnContinue () throw()
{
    CAtlServiceModuleT< CSimpleServiceModule, IDS_SERVICENAME >::OnContinue ();
}

void CSimpleServiceModule::OnPause () throw()
{
    CAtlServiceModuleT< CSimpleServiceModule, IDS_SERVICENAME >::OnPause ();
}

void CSimpleServiceModule::OnShutdown () throw()
{
    OnStop ();
}

void CSimpleServiceModule::OnStop () throw()
{
    CAtlServiceModuleT< CSimpleServiceModule, IDS_SERVICENAME >::OnStop ();
}

CSimpleServiceModule _AtlModule;


//
extern "C" int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE /*hInstance*/, HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, 
                                LPTSTR /*lpCmdLine*/, int nShowCmd)
{
    return _AtlModule.WinMain(nShowCmd);
}
```

Comment: Приведите релевантный код в тексте вопроса, так больше шансов получить ответ.

Comment: Принял, добавил код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас на второй машине не установлены рантаймы для C++. Если регистрировать сервис, как сказано в той статье через:

> SimpleService.exe -service

То вы увидите соответствующую ошибку о том, что нет необходимых библиотек.